# making the data wait for the declaration of variable finish on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I have this following code. what I want to do is to wait for the Values to be finish before it execute the dispatch.
what happening is that it dispatches and can only get the first value not the following foreach.

Thanks in advance

```
syncPO() {
    this.wait = true
    this.$store.dispatch('account/checkToken', this.optionValues.syncValue).then((res) => {
      this.wait = 'stepTwo'
      this.max = res.length
      res.forEach(result => {
            this.POValues.po_number = result.DocNumber
            this.POValues.vendor_id = result.VendorRef
            this.POValues.order_date=result.MetaData.CreateTime
            this.POValues.amount=result.TotalAmt
            this.POValues.currency=result.CurrencyRef
            this.POValues.qb_poId=result.Id
            this.POValues.status=result.POStatus
            this.POValues.line = result.Line
              this.$store.dispatch('purchaseOrder/createPO',this.POValues).then(res=>{
                  // console.log(this.POValues.line)
                this.value += 1;
              }).then((res)=>{
                this.$store.dispatch('purchaseOrder/create-lists')
              })
        })
      })

  },
```

Comment: Try using a Promise. [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things here.

You need to declare the function as async like

```
async syncPO(){  ...
```

Await the dispatch, not wait. The syntax is like

```
await this.$store.dispatch(
            'account/checkToken', this.optionValues.syncValue
        ).then((res) => {  ...
```

In order to get the dispatched action to return the promise you are awaiting, the actions must be a var, not a const

```
export var actions = { ...
```

If you are using axios, your data should be in `res.data`, not `res`.